# How to generate sql file with differences

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

I know a person that always generated sql files with the differences between the last version database and previos version, with Workbench but I don't know how generate this files. ¿It's with 2 databases or with 2 models ER?

For example, the option "Reverse Engineer" generate a model ER from a database

Comment: are you asking about incremental backup

Comment: Yes, I think that yes.